# Call POST request via Hangouts API from Google Scripts console

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, hangouts-api, google-hangouts

I've created a bot via Hangouts API and now would like to send a `POST` request to Google Calendar API ([Freebusy: query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query)) via Google Scripts console:

```js
function testPOST() {

    const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy";

    const datetimeMin = "2018-02-22T18:00:00.000Z";
    const datetimeMax = "2018-02-22T20:00:00.000Z";

    const payload = {
        calendarExpansionMax: 5,
        groupExpansionMax: 2,
        items: [{
            id: "%my_email@gmail.com%"
        }],
        timeMax: datetimeMax,
        timeMin: datetimeMin,
        timeZone: "Europe/Paris"
    }

    const options = {
        followRedirects: true,
        method: "POST",
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payload: payload
    };

    const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        const params = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
        Logger.log(params.name);
        Logger.log(params.blog);
    } else {
        Logger.log(result);
    }
}
```

During execution `result` is `null` or `undefined`, Google Console shows this object but it's empty. I checked, the default calendar of the specified email is public.

How to send a `POST`-request from Hangouts API via Google Scripts console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there were multiple issues with the code:

1. The `url` didn't contain the proper Google Calendar API key
2. The result has not been parsed to JSON

The correct code:

```js
function testPOST() {

    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key=%GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_KEY%';

    const datetimeMin = "2018-02-22T18:00:00.000Z";
    const datetimeMax = "2018-02-22T20:00:00.000Z";

    const payload = {
        calendarExpansionMax: 5,
        groupExpansionMax: 2,
        items: [{
            id: "%my_email@gmail.com%"
        }],
        timeMax: datetimeMax,
        timeMin: datetimeMin,
        timeZone: "Europe/Paris"
    }

    const options = {
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: "POST",
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
        timeZone: "CEST",
    };

    const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    
    Logger.log(result);
    
    if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        const params = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
        Logger.log(params.name);
        Logger.log(params.blog);
    } else {
        Logger.log(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Calendar API endpoint probably expects the payload to be a JSON encoded string. So update your options object as follows:

```
var options = {
    "method":"POST",
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "payload":JSON.stringify(payload)
}
```

Comment: Right, but there was one more issue — I forgot to provide a valid API key.